# Automock modules imported with node protocol in Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to use Jest manual mocking ([ref](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks)) with built-in Node.js modules that are imported using the `node:` protocol ([ref](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#node-imports)) in a TypeScript project. I can get this to work by, for example, creating a file in my project called `__mocks__/node:fs.ts` and calling `jest.mock("node:fs");` in my test.

However, `node:fs.ts` is an invalid file name on Windows due to the colon. So the question is: is there an alternative name that's compatible with Jest manual mocking that works with just calling `jest.mock("node:fs");`.

I tried two alternatives:

- Putting the mocks for builtin modules at `__mocks__/node/fs.ts`, as expected this didn't work.
- I currently landed at the non-ideal solution of mocking builtin modules like `jest.mock("node:fs", () => require("../path/to/the/node-fs.mock.ts"));`. This works, but is not a nice solution.

For reference, here's a link to a project where I'm having this issue: https://github.com/ericcornelissen/svgo-action/tree/b8a750b3738ba631e7be677ce03a90c90bab2783